# Can we Invoke AWS SNS service from snowflake external function through API gtw without lambda? must accept API query string parameters as well*

Tags: aws-api-gateway, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sns

I am able to make calls through snowflake external function(with parameters) to API gateway and then able to invoke lambda. Question is - "I want invoke SNS without lambda hence I also need to handle the parameters from snowflake function in API gateway itself which will be used to invoke SNS" is it possible ??

> Error: Request failed for external function EX_FN_API_EXCEPTIONS with
> remote service error: 400 '{"message": "Missing required request
> parameters: [subject, topicArn]"}'; requests batch-id: <>; request
> batch size: 1 rows; request retries: 0; response time (last retry):
> 41.9ms

```
create or replace external function EX_FN_API_EXCEPTIONS(subject1 varchar, topicArn1 varchar, message1 variant)
    returns variant
    api_integration = aws_api_integration_exceptions
    as 'https://tp7nyt3qq0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/event';
    
select EX_FN_API_EXCEPTIONS('TEST SNOW SUBJECT', 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:account:riksd-0015-notification', null )
```

All I need is how to pass parameters from snowflake external function to below method request's query string parameters and also the Message body

[image: Method Request Parameter]

[image: Integration Request parameters]

Comment: Could you share your external function definition?  You absolutely can use an external function to send a message to an SNS topic, but the error message seems to indicate that you aren't creating your payload correctly.

Comment: Updated the function code.. FYI- I am able to make calls from Postman to my API gtw after I exclude IAM authentication that I put in place for snowflake integration